# How to use awk to extract a line with exact match

Tags: regex, awk, grep, match, string-comparison

How do I use awk to search for an exact match in a file?

```
test.txt
hello10
hello100
hello1000
```

I have tried the following and it returns all 3 lines

```
awk '$0 ~ /^hello10/{print;}' test.txt
```

grep -w hello10 does the trick but on this box grep version is very limited and only few switches available

Answer (score 13):

To do a full line regular expression match you need to anchor at the beginning and the end of the line by using `^` and `$`:

```
$ awk '/^hello10$/' test.txt
hello10
```

But you're not actually using any regular expression features beside the anchoring we just added which means you actually want plain old string comparison:

```
$ awk '$0=="hello10"' test.txt
hello10
```

Comment: what if my pattern is stored in a variable and pass into the `awk`. For instance, `$1` contains the pattern and I do the following: `awk -v p="$1" '$0 ~ p {print NR}' myFile`. Then, how do I do exact matching, which matches the lines with exactly the pattern contained in `$1`? Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use \< \> to mark the edge of a word like \<hello10\>.

Comment: I get line1: Unexpected token.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression begins with a carat ^, which anchors the pattern to start at the beginning of the line. Try reading the manual page for awk to see if you can find a way to terminate a pattern at the end of the line, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed command

`sed -n '/\bhello10\b/p' test.txt`

Here \b indicates the boundary of the word you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

There is also word boundary /y in gawk

`awk '{if(match("hello10", sprintf("\y%s\y",$0)) print $0}' test.txt`