# how do I use awk to print starting at pattern, end at another pattern then exit?

Tags: awk

I have a text file that has the following format:

50000

55000

60000

65000

150000

160000

I want to print everything starting 50000 and ending at 60000. What I tried was:

```
awk "/50000/,/60000/ {print}"
```

But this also prints the 150000 and 160000. How should I modify this?

Comment: if you provide an 'end range' that doesn't exist in the file (eg, `70000`) what would you expect as the output? everything from `50000` to the end of the file, or nothing? similar question applies if the 'start ranges doesn't exist ... everything from beginning of file to 'end range' or nothing? and of course, if neither 'start/end range' exist in the file then what ... display entire file or nothing? other questions ... is the input file contents guaranteed to already be sorted (numerically)? is each number unique within the file or can a number occur more than once in the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use awk to extract a line with exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960758/how-to-use-awk-to-extract-a-line-with-exact-match)

Comment: Depends what you mean by "pattern" (see [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern)) and what else you might want to do (see [is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently with the ranges you get a partial match for 50000 in `150000`  and 60000 in `160000` and you are printing:

```
50000

55000

60000
```

and

```
150000

160000
```

If you want to match the whole line without partial matches, you can use anchors for the start and the end pattern.

```
awk '/^50000$/,/^60000$/' file
```

Comment: You can remove the `{print}` and let the default print operation handle the output.  I suspect you know that and have included it for readability.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry for the late response, I was not behind my machine. Thanks for the feedback, always a pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Robustly and efficiently you'd do:

```
awk '$1==50000{f=1} f{print; if ($1==60000) exit}' file
```

The `exit` is so awk doesn't continue wasting time reading the input long after the last line you want to process.

The above assumes that if 60000 didn't exist in the input but 50000 did then you'd want to print the lines from 50000 to the end of the file. If that's not the case then:

```
awk '$1==50000{f=1} f{ buf=buf $1 ORS; if ($1==60000) {printf "%s", buf; exit} }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice with awk is to not use a sed style regex range.

Instead, set a flag to start printing and another flag to stop (and perhaps exit.)

Example:

```
seq 100 | awk '
/^22$/{f=1}
/^29$/{exit}
f'
```

Prints:

```
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're not matching a regular expression you can set the criteria to equivalence instead

```
$ awk '$0==50000,$0==60000' file
```

will give you the desired range.

Comment: Like the succinct range expression and default print. (and since the other 2 answers are correct as well, each worthy of a nod)

Answer (score 1):

Also, numeric comparison works:

```
awk '50000 <= $1 && $1 <= 60000' file
```

The `print` is implicit here.

Answer (score 0):

you can also go for a string-based approach :

```
 gawk/nawk  '/^(5[0-9]{4}|6[0]{4})$/'

 mawk/mawk2 '/^(5[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|60000)$/'
```

I'd recommend against `[[:digit:]]` in place of `[0-9]` since `non-C/POSIX` locales may result in matching multi-byte "digits", such as those in Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I use awk to print starting at pattern, end at another pattern
> then exit?

If you are interestingly solely in first range, then just `exit` at first occurence of closing pattern, let `file.txt` content be

```
50000
55000
60000
65000
150000
160000
```

then

```
awk '/50000/,/60000/{print}/60000/{exit}' file.txt
```

output

```
50000
55000
60000
```

Note that this code will end processing as fast as encountering first `/60000/`, which is useful if you have huge file and are interested in first range which is placed near start.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*